# Why my map size is too small in Dash-Plotly App?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using python libraries called dash and plotly to create an interactive dashboard. I would like to set the map size to let it fill the whole Div. The map is created using mapbox. I tried to set style but not working.
My map looks like this:
[image: My Map]

I noticed other people’s map fill the whole Div. (See the position of widgets):
[image: Other person's map]

Here are my code:

```
map_data = [
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df['latitude'],
        lon=df['longitude'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            cmax=50,
            cmin=0,
            color=df['depth'],
            colorbar=dict(
                title='Colorbar'
            ),
            colorscale='YlGnBu',
            reversescale=True,
            size=5,
            # opacity=0.9
        ),

        text=df['depth'],
        hoverinfo='text'
    )
]

map_layout = go.Layout(
    title='Bathymetrical Data',
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    xaxis=dict(hoverformat='.5f'),
    yaxis=dict(hoverformat='.5f'),

    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=lat,
            lon=lon
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=10,
    ),
)

figure = {
    'data': map_data,
    'layout': map_layout
}
```

Dose anyone know how I can change my code to make my map looks like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is layout margins:

```
map_layout = go.Layout(
    title='Bathymetrical Data',
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
    ...
```

note that these margins affect the "inside" of the chart, you can also set the `width` and `height` parameters in the layout to change the size of the whole figure. For the width I strongly recommend using the css' grid on this [css](https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/dZVMbK.css) made for dash.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I would like to do.